# Web2py application is not launched with NGiNX

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, web2py

I have created a website with Web2py framework. To launch it on production, uWSGI app and NGiNX server were used as it was described [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/40/13/deployment-recipes#Nginx).

Both NGiNX and uWSGI are running, Web2py also does, but the website pages can not be opened. Browser returns error "502 Bad gateway". Please tell how can I fix this problem?

File /etc/nginx/sites-available/web2py :

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     $hostname;
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location ~* /(\w+)/static/ {
            root /home/www-data/web2py/applications/;
            #remove next comment on production
            #expires max;
        }
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
            uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name     $hostname;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/web2py.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/web2py.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        keepalive_timeout    70;
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/web2py.socket;
            include         uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
            uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        }

}
```

File /etc/init/uwsgi-emperor.conf :

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi --logto /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
```

File # /etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description = uWSGI Emperor
After = syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/web2py.ini
RuntimeDirectory = uwsgi
KillSignal = SIGQUIT
Type = notify
StandardError = syslog
NotifyAccess = all

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

File /etc/uwsgi/web2py.ini

```
[uwsgi]

socket = /tmp/web2py.socket
pythonpath = /home/www-data/web2py/
mount = /=wsgihandler:application
processes = 4
master = true
harakiri = 60
reload-mercy = 8
cpu-affinity = 1
stats = /tmp/stats.socket
max-requests = 2000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
touch-reload = /home/www-data/web2py/routes.py
cron = 0 0 -1 -1 -1 python /home/www-data/web2py/web2py.py -Q -S welcome -M -R scripts/sessions2trash.py -A -o
no-orphans = true
vacuum = true
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/web2py.log
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot it? Does `/tmp/web2py.socket` exist? Check with `file /tmp/web2py.socket`

Comment: File exists, this command returns value ```/tmp/web2py.socket: socket```. To troubleshoot the problem, only emperor.uwsgi and nginx statuses were viewed. I'd like to know other ways to check errors